# Capture Specific String in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to capture a specific sequence of letters and numbers in a CSV field.
The field can contain the following:

"Some random text WMM540" < cell text

EDIT: Here's the raw csv:

```
Employee ID,First Name,Surname,Base Store Code,Job Title  
555555,Mark,Testing-Process,Mo Newcastle Under Lyme WMM222,Merchandiser  
555556,Carly,O'Test,AS Congleton ASD1111,Supervisor
```

I need to capture the `WMMXXX` (where `X` is the number) in a variable, but there can be more codes. The possible codes I need to get are:

```
WMMXXX  
MORXXX  
ASDXXXX (4 digits instead of 3)  
WILXXX  
PLDXXX  
SUPXXX
```

.. and a few more.

I'm aware you can split and isolate text using regex, but I don't have enough experience with it.
Ultimately I need a variable that looks like: `$v = 'WMMXXX'`

Please could you help?

Many thanks

Comment: Something like `$v = if ($cellValue -match '((?:WMM|MOR|WIL|PLD|SUP)\d{3}|ASD\d{4})') { $matches[1] }` should work, but we really need more details...

Comment: If it is always the last space-separated token, regardless of its content: `$v = $cellValue -replace '^.* '`. This simply strips everything up to and including the last space from the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer

Since you apparently only want to find very specific codes, you can do something likt this:

```
$regex = '((?:WMM|MOR|WIL|PLD|SUP)\d{3}|ASD\d{4})'
Import-Csv -Path 'PathToTheFile.csv' | ForEach-Object {
     if ($_.'Base Store Code' -match $regex) { $matches[1] }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, accepted and very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- It sounds like you ultimately need a *regex* to extract the substring of interest, as shown in [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66078510/45375).
- This answer shows a simplified approach based on the assumption that the substring of interest is always the *last whitespace-separated token* in the column of interest.

---

Use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), extract the column values of interest (column `Base Store Code`), and extract the *last* whitespace-separated token from each, which the unary form of `-split`, the [string-splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) allows you to do (index `[-1]` returns the *last* element of the resulting array):

```
Import-Csv in.csv | ForEach-Object { (-split $_.'Base Store Code')[-1] }
```

With your sample data as input, this yields:

```
WMM222
ASD1111
```